# PowerShell Date Comparison

Tags: powershell, csv, date, date-comparison

**Goal: Import dates from CSV. If date has already passed or is today, display it.**

```
$dayInOctober = (Get-date).AddDays(90)
$csvname = "myCSV.csv"
$csvFile = Import-Csv C:\Users\a341162\Desktop\$csvname

foreach($row in $csvFile){
    if ($row.Date -le $dayInOctober){
        Write-Host $row.Date
    }
}
```

But only works if I make the if statement `-gt`. Shouldn't it be the way I have it above?

myCSV.csv:

```
"Name","Date"
"admryantest2","7/20/2018"
"admryantest3","7/20/2018"
"admryantest3","7/23/2018"
"admryantest3","7/23/2018"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you import the CSV, $row.Date is a string. If you want to compare dates ***as dates*** then you need to convert it to a date:

```
$dayInOctober = (Get-date).AddDays(90)
$csvname = "myCSV.csv"
$csvFile = Import-Csv C:\Users\a341162\Desktop\$csvname

foreach($row in $csvFile){
    if ((Get-Date $row.Date) -le $dayInOctober){
        Write-Host $row.Date
    }
}
```

Then you can use -le as expected.